# How to operate on a certain element when blur?

Tags: jquery, blur

When focusing,we can do something like:

```
$('#target').focus(function(){$(this)..});
```

Because "this" is just the one that's focused(`$(this) == $('#target')`).

But can't do the same for "blur",because `$(this) != $('#target')`.

How to do it the right way?

NOTE:
in my application,I can't assign an id to the target,and '#target' here is just for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blur will keep the context as you'd expect:

```
$("#target").blur(function() {
    $(this).text("See? It works!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = $('target');
foo.focus(function(){foo.....});
```

The anonymous function will act as a closure and will remember the value of foo.

Comment: In fact I can only use class name as selector,and there are multiple ones with that class name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to access 'this' with blur, the following code is working ok...

```
$(".aClass").blur(
  function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Event/blur](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur) triggers the blur event of each matched element and $(this) return just the one that's blured.

```
jQuery("#target").blur(function() {
  console.log( jQuery(this) );
});
```

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/index.html). It also add a global variable named "console" to all web pages loaded in Firefox. In this case "console.log" writes a message to the console.